# How do I keep a double button press on a UIButton from cancelling the action?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that when clicked starts searching for data. But while searching, if the user clicks on the button again it cancels the search.

Relevant Code:

```
    - (void)searchAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [sender removeTarget:self action:@selector(searchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelSearch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
    [animatedImages startAnimating];
    //action that should be done

}

- (void)cancelSearch:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender removeTarget:self action:@selector(cancelSearch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(searchNearbyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [animatedImages stopAnimating];

}
```

So the basic idea is that when i click on it its function change to cancel and vice-verca

The problem is that when I click on it the first time, it calls `searchAction` and then calls `cancelSearch` for no reason.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: You had a fairly lucid, well-written explanation, but your last line compromises the quality of your question.  "plz if someone can explain me what's happening ?? thanks" is not a good way to get people to answer your question.  Try this, on a new line:
"Does anyone know why this might be happening?  Thanks!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround is to add a BOOL as an instance variable

```
BOOL canCancel;
```

and then do the following

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
      if (!canCancel) {
           // action that should be done
           canCancel = YES;
      } else if (canCancel) {
           // cancel action
           canCancel = NO;
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response.Is this the proper way to do it? i thought that separating them might be cleaner. do u have any idea what's wrong with my solution?